# How to pass a parameter to a thread and get a return value?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class CalculationThread implements Runnable {

    int input;
    int output;

    public CalculationThread(int input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void run() {
        output = input + 1;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new CalculationThread(1));
thread.start();
int result = thread.getResult();
```

Of course, `thread.getResult()` doesn't work (it tries to invoke this method from the `Thread` class).

You get what I want. How can I achieve this in Java?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This a job for thread pools. You need to create a `Callable<R>` which is `Runnable` returning a value and send it to a thread pool.

The result of this operation is a `Future<R>` which is a pointer to this job which will contain a value of the computation,  or will not if the job fails.

```
public static class CalculationJob implements Callable<Integer> {
    int input;

    public CalculationJob(int input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return input + 1;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    Future<Integer> result = executorService.submit(new CalculationJob(3));

    try {
        Integer integer = result.get(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        System.out.println("result: " + integer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // interrupts if there is any possible error
        result.cancel(true);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Prints:

```
result: 4
```

Comment: What if I don't want Future<Integer> result = executorService.submit(new CalculationThread(3)); to get completed completely and I want to use Future object in parallel like a  BlockingQueue similar to this one https://github.com/manish436/WeatherServiceManager

Comment: @MarwanJaber Good point. The name of the job is misleading. Instead of 'CalculationThread', it should be named a 'CalculationJob'. Executor by itself is stateless for the user.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is great. But it is not the simplest approach. There's no real need to use an ExecutorService if you just want to wait for the result of a thread. You can simply use [`java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), which is basically a `Runnable` wrapping a `Callable` which also implements the `Future` interface.

So step 1 is still make the calculation a `Callable` :

```
public class Calculation implements Callable<Integer> {

    private final int input;

    public Calculation(int input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return input + 1;
    }
}
```

So where you need the asynchronous calculation you can do :

```
    FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<>(new Calculation(1561));
    new Thread(task).start();

    // ... do other stuff

    // when I really need the result :

    try {
        int result = task.get(); // this will wait for the task to finish, if it hasn't yet.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.getCause().printStackTrace(); // e.getCause() holds the exception that happened on the calculation thread
    }
```

What the `ExecutorService` adds is managing a pool of threads to run the task on, but under the hood of an `ExecutorService`, basically the same thing happens.

Comment: What if I actually need to run a few threads? I understand that `ExecutorService` is a better choice then, right?

Comment: ExecutorService is almost always the better choice. It's more scalable, it intelligently handles threads for you... I just felt the simple answer hadn't been given. In really simple cases my answer may be the better choice.

Comment: I have upvoted because this answers the main question more directly. Although "Executors" is the way to go, it's still cool to know this is not impossible.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for Callable. It's a Runnable on steroids, it can return a result. Check the javadoc:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Here is a tutorial: http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example

Answer (score 3):

Old school style

```
public class CalculationThread extends Thread {

    int input;
    int output;

    public CalculationThread(int input){
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void run() {
        output = input + 1;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return output;
    }
}

CalculationThread thread = new CalculationThread(1);
thread.start();
thread.join();
int result = thread.getResult();
```

Comment: Won't work, because `Thread` doesn't implement the `getResult()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor and pass value by reference.

```
public CalculationThread(int[] input)
```

Do you want to pass the value of `int` to the thread called `CalculationThread` you should create a thread but if you pass a parameter by value the thread can use that value but you can't get the data back. Passing it by reference you can modify the value but not reference in the thread and the reference if it's available to both threads point to the value which is modifiable in both threads. Of cause you code should be synchronized to share the same reference.

Comment: Could you explain a little more? I don't understand how does this help me.