# Pass Dynamically Created ArrayList<JButton> Index to ActionListener Class

Tags: java, arraylist, actionlistener

First off thanks for everyone who contributes. It's such a lifesaver. That said, here's my first ever post.

I've created a dynamic array of JButton objects and attached an ActionListener to the button.

```
public void printFound(ArrayList<Customer> found)
{       
    buttons = new ArrayList();
    texts = new ArrayList();
    for(Customer temp: found)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Edit");
        btn.addActionListener(new PushEdit());
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        panel1.add(btn);
        buttons.add(btn);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(temp.toString(), 8, 80);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        panel1.add(text);
        texts.add(text);
    }
}
```

When I click on an edit button, I want it to pass the index of "btn" in "buttons" to the ActionListener so that I can display the values in "temp" in another GUI. I figure I either need to pass temp directly or I need to pass both the index of "btn" as well as the index of "found".

Thanks!

Comment: Found my answer here. Do I need to mark this duplicate now or delete?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20221408/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-a-thread-and-get-a-return-value

Answer (score 0):

as i can understand from your question you want to get the index of the `jbutton` that stored in `buttons ArrayList` to do some sort of things..

to do this you can use `setActionCommand` and `getActionCommand` methods to bind a String along with every `jbutton` that created and

so your code will be like this

```
public void printFound(ArrayList<Customer> found)
{       
    buttons = new ArrayList();
    texts = new ArrayList();
    Integer index=0;
    for(Customer temp: found)
    {
        JButton btn = new JButton("Edit");
        btn.setActionCommand(index.toString());
        btn.addActionListener(new PushEdit());
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 40));
        panel1.add(btn);
        buttons.add(btn);
        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(temp.toString(), 8, 80);
        text.setLineWrap(true);
        panel1.add(text);
        texts.add(text);

        index=index+1;
    }
}
```

whenever you you want to get the index

```
System.out.print(btn.getActionCommand());
```